# Server responds with "error : invalid image" to java http post request containing base64 image

Tags: java, http, post, base64

I am setting up a client written in Java which is supposed to send 2 base64 encoded images to a Server. The server responds with "error : invalid image"
Apart from that, the Post request is supposedly formulated correctly.
What am I missing here?

This is the official documentation on the web API I am using:
https://documenter.getpostman.com/view/5211511/RWaDYCUN#49003cb5-55d7-d363-bb64-d202fd8d9cd7
I am specifically using the compare-faces endpoint.

this.address contains the correct Url to the endpoint and the variables 
image_camera and image_user contain instances of type BufferedImage.

```
public String compare() {

    String form1_64, form2_64;

    ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    Base64.Encoder encoder = Base64.getEncoder();
    try {
        String form1_net = "data:image/png;base64";
        String form2_net = "data:image/png;base64";
        // TODO invalid image file in FaceX response
        ImageIO.write(image_camera, "png", bos);
        form1_64 = encoder.encodeToString(bos.toByteArray());
        ImageIO.write(image_user, "png", bos);
        form2_64 = encoder.encodeToString(bos.toByteArray());
        form1_net += form1_64;
        form2_net += form2_64;

        String url = String.valueOf(this.address);
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost post = new HttpPost(url);

        List<NameValuePair> urlParams = new ArrayList<>();
        urlParams.add(new BasicNameValuePair("image_attr", form1_net));
        urlParams.add(new BasicNameValuePair("image_attr", form2_net));

        post.setHeader("user_id", "my-user-id");
        post.setHeader("user_key", "my-user-key");

        post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(urlParams));

        HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);

        BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));
        StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer();
        String line;
        while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
            result.append(line);
        }

        System.out.println(result.toString());

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return null;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to use postman and send it manual?

Comment: @KunLun could you explain that? :)

Comment: You can use [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/) to create an HTTP request and send it. It is very useful to test if microservice work right or not, and after that you can know if it's a problem from code or microservice.

Comment: If you don't get how to use Postman come here https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188668/room-for-kunlun-and-alexander-tepe to help you.